# VScode - mySQL - error "Client option 'pooling.maxIdleTime' does not support value 'NaN'." when connecting a database in VSCode?

Tags: mysql-connector

Has anyone run into this issue on vscode mysql?

I am not able to find any solution on this.

**client option 'pooling.maxidletime' does not support value 'nan'
**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpsOt.jpg)

Here´s the error.

If anyone has any idea or has come across this, the help would be greatly appreciated.

Connection MYSQL failiure